# the jQuery File is saved but not changing in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, web-deployment

I've made some changes on my jquery code and saved it but when opening the browser the code [Image 1](https://i.s)hasn't been changed it's still the same as I didn't save it!.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uBLq.png)tack.imgur.com/ceyf8.png

Comment: Not what you're asking, but you'll need to move all those assignments *inside* the submit, otherwise you get the values at page load.

Comment: Please add more detail for the question

Comment: Are you sure you've saved it to the correct place?  Have you tried refreshing without cache? Clearing the cache?  Using debugging tools to always load without cache?  Trying with an empty file?  Seen what it says in the browser network tab (hint "loaded from cache")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear the cache by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> this will clear the cache and load the saved file.